# Is it possible to attach an sqlite database in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, sqlite, web-sql

Is it possible to do something like this?

```
mDB = openDatabase("mainDB","1.0","Main Database",5 * 1024 * 1024);
sDB = openDatabase("subDB","1.0","Sub Database",5 * 1024 * 1024);

mDB.transaction(function(tx){
    tx.executeSql("ATTACH DATABASE subDB as sub", []);
});
```

This code is not working, though. In the SQL statement, the word subDB should really be a file reference according to the spec. This works fine in the sqlite3 CLI, but what should it be in Javascript code? It seemed natural to use the shortName specified in the openDatabase command, but obviously this did not work.

Answer (score 0):

WebSQL does not give access to the database file name, so this is not possible.